# What is the definition of scheme over a field?

Tags: schemes

For a fixed scheme $S$, a scheme *over $S$* is defined to be a scheme $X$ together with a morphism $X \to S.$ I am following Hartshorne, and I cannot find a definition of scheme *over a field $k$.* Is it a scheme $X$ together with a morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$?

Comment: Sorry, but what you wrote in answer could very well have been a comment, in which case my deletion would perhaps have been valid.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is it. If your scheme $X$ is affine, this is the same thing as an algebra over the field $k$, hence the terminology.

Comment: I have a question to your answer. As I understand it, if $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a $k$-scheme, then $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a scheme with a morphism of schemes $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow (\operatorname{Spec}(k),\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}(k)})$. But in my opinion since $k$ is a field $\operatorname{Spec}(k)=\{(0)\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, there is only one maximal ideal in a field.

Comment: But I would then have a morphism $X\rightarrow \{(0)\}$ wouldn't there be only one such morphism?

Comment: @user123234 A morphism of schemes is not just a continuous map, it's a map of ringed spaces. You also need to give a morphism between the structure sheaves. There can be multiple different ones, even with affine schemes. For example, complex conjugation is a ring morphism which is not the identity, so there are at least two different morphisms $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C} \to \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: But there is only one continuous map and then several morphism of structure sheaves?

Comment: @user123234 Yes.